# After inserting camera plugin Eclipse show errors

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

After inserting Camera plugin via PhoneGap command line interface :

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

eclipse give me this errors :

```
Description Resource Path Location Type
TAG_ISO cannot be resolved or is not a field    ExifHelper.java /PRName/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 148    Java Problem
TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME cannot be resolved or is not a field  ExifHelper.java /PRName/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 112    Java Problem
TAG_APERTURE cannot be resolved or is not a field   ExifHelper.java /PRName/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 106    Java Problem
TAG_ISO cannot be resolved or is not a field    ExifHelper.java /PRName/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 87 Java Problem
TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME cannot be resolved or is not a field  ExifHelper.java /PRName/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 75 Java Problem
TAG_APERTURE cannot be resolved or is not a field   ExifHelper.java /PRName/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 73 Java Problem
```

How to fix this?

Cleaning and building project doesn't work ... 
Also tried removing and adding plugin again, also didn't work ...

---

Edit: 
I have commented error lines of code and it is working for now... Anyone have any clue why is this happaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue:

removing all plugins installed like `cordova plugin add <plugin name>` and installing them again via plugman `plugman --platform <platform name> --project <path to project specified platform> --plugin <plugin name>` and after that installing BarcodeScanner plugin via plugman worked as charm ...